# jquery cookie, save cookies in where?

Tags: jquery, cookies

Maybe this is a basic question. but I still not sure `jquery cookie`, save cookies in where?

like this one: http://code.google.com/p/cookies/wiki/Documentation

the cookies save in server part or in custom browser part?

I guess save in custom browser part. `jquery cookie` just is a tool, it should be like php `cookie/session`, save each cookie depends on different `URL`.

But when I see it need set `domain` and `path`. I am puzzed, if it depends on different `URL`, why not use `domain` + `window.location.hash`? the `path` for what?

Comment: Try reading: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html (Specifically, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#link5)

Comment: good introduce, set `path`  `/` means all the domain. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"JQuery cookie" is a simple tool which makes use of `document.cookie`. This basic JavaScript feature stores cookies at the user's browser.

A cookie can be defined with some properties:

- `max-age` - Expiration date in seconds (Jquery implementation: `{expires: __}` in days)
- `domain` - By default, a cookie is saved at the current domain. It's however possible to change the domain to any domain from the current subdomain to the top domain (`sub.sub2.top.nl` -> `sub2.top.nl` -> `top.nl`, but *not* `another.top.nl`).
- `path` - By default, the cookie is applied to `/`. It's possible to change this default, so that only a specific directory is matched.
- `secure` - This flag can be added through passing `secure: true` in JQuery. When this option is set, cookies are targeted at the HTTPS protocol only.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the domain.  I was trying to set the cookie to another domain and not getting any error message, but now I know why.